# Is there a way to find if there relationship of numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, computational-mathematics

I have a challenge. This may be little tricky or even not possible but wanted to check if anyone has any thoughts on this?

PS : This question is in general and not related to only to R. May be I can say its general mathematics

I have a data

```
df
ColA    ColB    ColC
 6       9       27
 1       4       32
 4       8       40
```

If you observe closely, there is some relationship between these columns.

Example, (ColC/ColB)+ColA will give you number 9.

```
df
ColA    ColB    ColC   ColD
 6       9       27     9
 1       4       32     9
 4       8       40     9
```

However this data is manipulated and I made sure there is some relation. But in general, lets us take any numbers, is there a way to find if there is any relationship between these numbers. Need not be (ColC/ColB)+ColA . It could be anything.

Say we have 5 columns of numeric data. I need to find mathematical operation between these so that common number exists.

Can anyone help

This is more into mathematics(algebra). Can anyone let me know is this even possible ?

Comment: Given a set of $n$ pairs of numbers, it is always possible to find a polynomial of degree at most $n$ which goes through all those points.

Comment: Malady is correct, and the conclusion you need to get from that fact is that for *any* finite set of data, you can find all sorts of formulas that hold for it. However, whether the formulas you find are useful - that is, whether they have any *predictive* power for new data that will be collected in the future - is not so clear. Most of the formulas you can find are going to be coincidences, and new data will not match it. But without knowing where the data is coming from, the only way to test if a formula is useful is to collect a lot more data.

Comment: @Malady thanks. Can you share more details if you do not mind. Do you have any reference material for this?

Comment: @manup Lagrange interpolation: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html